# .NET authentication for two separate applications using the same Web API

Tags: .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication

Here is my situation:

I have two separate .NET web applications. They have their own forms authentication systems, their own users, and they know nothing about each other. I need to create a third application that exists outside of both that lets the users from one application communicate with the users of the other. I would like to create a SignalR messaging Web API that users from both of these systems can use.

How would I go about dealing with the authentication for the Web API service? I'm not sure how to go about combining the authenticated users from two separate systems. Is that even possible? Does each application have to create its own separate authentication token for the Web API somehow?

Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!